# Why XML is not showing in usual manner in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate, maven

Created hibernateCfg.xml manually in eclipse and it is  not showing up in usual script format instead shown a tabular form with columns as "node" and "version".How to resolve it ?

I was expecting regular format usually we see for other java files ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you opened it with XML editor. To resolve this follow these steps:

1. Locate the XML file - in package explorer in Eclipse IDE only  **Window** > **Show View** > **Package explorer**.
2. Right click on the XML file.
3. Select **Open With as Text Editor**.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the bottom of the editor pane for tabs to switch to the Source page.